# How to get all dates from a list of string

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a big list like this:

```
s3_path=['path/temp/2020-01-01/test1.csv','path/temp/2020-01-02/test2.csv']
```

I want to create a list which will have all the date fields present in the list item. How can I achieve this in efficient way?

Output would be:

```
date_list=['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex.

```
import re

date_list = re.findall(r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})', ' '.join(s3_path))

# OR
# date_list = [re.findall(r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})', s)[0] for s in s3_path]
```

```
>>> date_list
['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02']
```